# How to add LVL to my non-gradle project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lvl

I have had to modify one old app, developed in Eclipse. I have working with Android Studio, and I need to integrate License Verification Library in the project, but it is not a gradle project, so I don't know how to put the files, reading the documentation of google, I'm not able to achieve this.

I have downloaded the play licensing from the SDK. My project has assests, res, libs, gen, and src folders. What I need to do?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is compiling fine in Android Studio, then that means that it already has gradle. Import the LVL into your project as a module, then add it to the app module's gradle build script as a dependency.